# Clarifying some elementary Orbit and Stabilizer questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have some elementary questions in learning about groups and I just want to be sure I am on the right track. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Let $A = \{  \begin{pmatrix}   a & b  \\   0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} |
\space a,b \in \mathbb{R} , a > 0   \} $ and $ B = \{  \begin{pmatrix}
j & 0  \\   0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} | \space j \in \mathbb{R} , j > 0  \} $

> (i) Show that $A$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{R}) $
>
> (ii) Let $A$ act on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual way. Describe the
>   orbit and stabilizer of both  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} $
>   and $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$
>
> (iii) Give a brief reason why $B$ is a subgroup of $A$

For (i), I can easily show that $A$ is closed under multiplication and inversion, **but is it necessary to state first that $A$ is indeed a subset of  $GL(2,\mathbb{R}) $?**

For (ii), I have that the orbit of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} $ is $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} $, where $a \in (0,\infty)$ (i.e. the positive $x$ axis)
and the stabiliser are matrices: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $  and the orbit of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} $ is $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} $, where $b \in (-\infty,\infty)$ (i.e. the horizontal line along $y=1$)
and the stabiliser are matrices: $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $.

**Would these be correct?**

Finally for (iii), it seems like this question is a bit of a repeat of (i), however, it does say a 'brief reason'. **Is there a quicker way to show that $B$ is a subgroup of $A$, other than showing that it is closed under inversion and multiplication (essentially repeating the steps of (i)?**

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i) No, it is clear that $A$ is a subset of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ if $A$ is a group.

ii) This is correct.

iii) you have just shown that this is the stabilizer of the following vector! \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} Since the stabilizer of an element is a subgroup of the group, this is true! If you would like proof of this lemma [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Stabilizer_is_Subgroup) it is.